# FTP user getting locked - What to check?

Tags: linux, ftp

This time I have another question. This one is related to FTP. We have an ftp server say 127.0.0.2. The application server is on ip say 127.0.0.1. From the application server, we connect to the FTP server every 10 minutes and pull or push certain files in the INWARD and OUTWARD folders respectively.

The ftp server is running linux with the following details:

```
-bash-3.2$ uname -n
ftpserver.companyname.com
-bash-3.2$ uname
Linux
-bash-3.2$ uname -r
2.6.18-308.13.1.el5
```

The problem is that the FTP user gets locked automatically on a random basis. Random meaning really random... This instance it is working but within the next 15 seconds it will get locked triggering of an alert and thus requiring user intervention to get it unlocked.

To check when the locking is happening, we wrote a monitoring shell script to check the ftp connection every 15 seconds. This script will only connect to the ftp machine and quit. If everything is ok, it will not do anything but if connection fails it will mail the stake holders with the ftp log.

SCRIPT >>

```
ftp -niv $FTP_HOST <<END_SCRIPT > $FTP_LOG
quote USER $FTP_USER
quote PASS $FTP_PASSWD
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Now if we see the log generated from the script, we can see the below information:

LOG >>

```
::::: DATE/TIME = Wed Apr 23 17:35:00 UTC 2014 :::::
Step 1 complete : Initialised log file ~/ftp_support_23_Apr_2014.log
Step 2 complete : Completed check for ftp login
FTP connection to 127.0.0.2 is ok.
Step 3 completed. Deleted ftp.log

::::: DATE/TIME = Wed Apr 23 17:35:15 UTC 2014 :::::
Step 1 complete : Initialised log file ~/ftp_support_23_Apr_2014.log
Step 2 complete : Completed check for ftp login
FTP user username is locked on 127.0.0.2.
Step 3 completed. Deleted ftp.log

----- SAME OUTPUT AS ABOVE EVERY 15 SECONDS TILL USER IS UNLOCKED ------
```

Here the ftp user was unlocked by the SA.

```
::::: DATE/TIME = Wed Apr 23 17:41:40 UTC 2014 :::::
Step 1 complete : Initialised log file ~/ftp_support_23_Apr_2014.log
Step 2 complete : Completed check for ftp login
FTP connection to 127.0.0.2 is ok.
Step 3 completed. Deleted ftp.log
```

Now the question that we all have is what could have happened in 15 seconds causing the user to get locked? At 17:35:00 UTC the connection is ok, at 17:35:15 UTC, the connection goes dead. The log which is mailed to the stake holders is as below -

MAILED FTP LOG >>

```
Connected to 127.0.0.2.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
331 Please specify the password.
530 Login incorrect.
221 Goodbye.
```

Now we know for sure, that the password is read from a encrypted config file and used by the program. If it works every 10 mins, then there is no problem with the program sending the password to the ftp user. And any system user is not typing in the password incorrectly. Hence the question here is **what do we need to check at our end?**

How do we interpret the `530 Login incorrect.` error message? Can anyone suggest what we have to do here? Has the SA changed any setting on the ftp server? What can we ask them to check at OS level or for the ftp service?

If the output of any command is needed or if any running service needs to be checked, let me know.

Comment: This sounds like some security feature implemented in that FTP server which "locks" accounts/sessions with too many concurrent sessions. There probably is a configuration switch for such feature. I suggest you consult the documentation of the ftp server software.

Comment: thanks. I will confirm with the SA team. Anything else to be checked? Can you please also confirm what exactly is the documentation of the ftp server software? Is it the Man page for the ftp?

Comment: Hi @arkascha, we checked the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file, but did not find any limit specified on the max no of ftp connections to the machine. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: My bad, the service is vsftpd. (is it secureFtp and not a simple ftp?) the line in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` reads `pam_service_name=vsftpd`

Comment: One could see from the log files you posted that this actually is a vsftpd you are using. I am not aware of such a feature in it either but I also never have seen such logging output. Interesting. Frankly I have no idea what this 'locking' actually refers to...

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. By locking I mean, that if we try to ftp to the machine by typing the ftp command and putting in the username and password, it will display the message as `Your account is locked. Maximum amount of failed attempts was reached`

Comment: To rule out the possibility of an incorrect password, we also checked the encoding on both machines. It is `en_US.UTF-8`. So the password should not be the problem; is what we feel.

Comment: Ah, ok, got that different from the log excerpts you posted: I thought the login succeeds, but _afterwards_ the account gets somehow "locked"...

Comment: Is that a single process in the client that initiates the connections or are those multiple processes, though do you face the danger of deadlocks and concurrent connections? Maybe those "failed" attempts are connections that got disconnected before the login succeeds. A timeout, a script unable to read a file, or similar? As a last resort you can always dump the network traffic and then examine the packages sent in the connection that lead to such a locked effect.

Comment: @arkascha On the application server, there are multiple scripts (12 to be precise) for multiple customers, all doing the same task, i.e. pulling/pushing files from/to in/out folders. Earlier, all used to run at the same time. However this 'locking' problem was faced earlier and we re-scheduled each of the cron jobs to run 5 mins after the previous one. We haven't faced any problems with concurrent connections after this change. We are also in touch with the SA team to check for any other problems.

Comment: Do all of those scripts terminate (apart from those obviously blocked by getting "locked")? Are there logfiles for the scripts to check this?

Comment: Yes, all scripts terminate correctly. I will see if I can post the log files for these scripts after editing. Since they could contain classified information, I am not sure if I can post them here. The programs are working fine since the last 2 years or so, no changes done to them. So what we don't get is that in a day the scripts work perfectly fine for 95% of the time. Only once or twice a day the ftp user account gets locked.

Comment: Ok, no need to invest time into editing the log files. I suggest you start dumping the network traffic. you need to be able to see what is going on right before such incident occurs. You can use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` for this.

Comment: @arkascha, thanks for the suggestion. We will do that and see what happens. Will keep this thread posted.